# UFT descriptive programming Browser("creationtime:=-1") not always working

Tags: qtp

I am using the following code to highlight browser instance (only 1 browser instance exists)

```
Browser("CreationTime:=-1").highlight
```

Sometimes the code is highlighting the only browser instance available while sometimes it is showing "No object found". I have read in QTP unplugged by tarun lalwani that if 1 browser instance exists then `Browser("CreationTime:=-1").exist(5)` will return true. Please tell what i am doing wrong or understanding wrong here.

I am trying to do certain operations if only 1 browser instance is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CreationTime` property is a selector, selectors are used only if the rest of the description isn't unique. This means that if there is only one browser, QTP/UFT will not look at the `CreationTime` you specified and will not care that the value you gave is invalid (`CreationTime` should be a non-negative integer).

Once there are more than one browsers (if you think there's only one, either you or QTP are mistaken...) QTP will look at the selector and see it has an invalid value and tell you that the object wasn't found.

I don't see the point of using this description, if you think that only one browser exists a more logical description would be `"micclass:=Browser"` that way you'll get an informative error (object not unique/found) when QTP fails to find the object.

---

**Edit**

If you want to detect if there is only one browser you can do it in two different ways.

```
Public Function ThereIsOneBrowser
       On Error Resume Next
       Browser("title:=.*").GetROProperty "title"
       If Err Then
            ThereIsOneBrowser = False
       Else               
            ThereIsOneBrowser = True
       End If
       On Error Goto 0 ' Cancel On Error Resume next
End Function

Public Function NumberOfBrowsers
    Set desc = Description.Create()
    desc("micclass").Value = "Browser"
    NumberOfBrowsers = Desktop.ChildObjects(desc).Count
End Function
```

Pros and cons of each method:

- `ThereIsOneBrowser` will wait the object identification timeout if there are no browsers (by default 20 seconds) so it's slower
- I'm not sure if `Desktop.ChildObjects` knows how to interact with Mobile Center (MC) so if you're sometimes testing mobile devices this may give you the wrong result

If you're not testing mobile I would go for `NumberOfBrowsers`.

Comment: Actually, i am trying to find difference between 1 instance and multiple instances of browser. micclass:=Browser will return true for both true instance and multiple instances of browser.

Comment: No it won't, it will succeed for one browser and fail for multiple

Comment: I will accepted the answer as solution. But can you please tell where is my understanding wrong regarding creationtime value as -1

Comment: @SOUMYADEEPBASUCHOWDHURY please see my edit on how to know if the browser is unique. As for why I say it's wrong to use `-1` see what I said about `creationTime` being a _non-negative integer_

Comment: Thanks for the response.So, I can check if there is only 1 browser instance by using the Browser("micclass:=Browser").exist() which returns true if there is only 1 instance of browser else returns false. I can also use NumberOfBrowsers which will be 1 for one browser else value will be >1. I can also use ThereIsOneBrowser where if multiple browser exists,  Browser("title:=.*").GetROProperty "title" will throw error and for On Error Resume Next, ThereIsOneBrowser will be false. Can you plz tell whether my understanding is correct or not & also creationtime:=-1 written in book is correct or not.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Using `-1` as a creation time is sort of OK  but it depends on internal behaviour of UFT that doesn't look at the `creationTime` at all if the rest of the description is enough. In the future UFT may change to validate it got a legal value for `creationTime` even if it doesn't use it and if this happens then it will fail so I would avoid it myself (although it's probable that such a breaking change will never happen)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have accepted the answer as solution

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one browser instance open than the **`CreationTime`** will be **`0`** instead of **`1`** as it starts from **`0`**.

So if you have two browser instance than 1st opened browser's CreationTime will be 0 and 2nd opened Browser's CreationTime will be 1.

Comment: For two browser instance, i am getting correct response. But when only 1 browser instance is present, Browser("creationtime:=-1") is sometimes highlighting the browser and sometimes it is giving error "no object found". I am trying to do certain operations if only 1 browser instance is present. Browser("creationtime:=0") will exist for both 1 instance of browser and multiple instances of browser